# Send boost::property_tree::ptree pt to server c++

Tags: c++, linux, client-server

I have client-server application (C++, Linux) and I would like to send my `boost::property_tree::ptree pt (object)` from client to server.

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you give some more information? Because you aren't telling us what you have tried already ?

Comment: I have got object ptree (for JSON) and want send this object to my server. But function send(sock, data, strlen(data), 0); can`t send my object to server only text.

Comment: And can't you just send the object formatted as a text to the server? And on the server you can translate it back to an object?